# Using corner-stamp with the isFitWidth option in Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

Does anyone know how to use the corner-stamp with the "isFitWidth" option in Masonry? The items don't arrange themselves properly when the window is resized back.

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.span1BoxWrapper',
    cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp',
    columnWidth: 322,
    isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions, 
    //isRTL: true 
    isFitWidth: true 
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with cornerstamp and isfitwidth the masonry layout did not reload when I initially resized the window, leaving “bricks” out of place. If I moved the window size slightly it would then reload, but this bugged me. To fix this I just added a timer that reloads masonry every 50ms. Probably not efficient code but it fixes the bug until someone figures it out in a more elegant way.

```
window.onload = function () {
   setInterval(function(){
      $(“#container”).masonry(‘reload’);
   },50);
   ...
   ...
}
```